# deploying Azure webjob from VS2013 with schedule

Tags: azure, deployment, scheduling, azure-webjobs

I'm having some trouble setting the schedule for a webjob I'm deploying to Azure.
I need the job to be executed at 8 AM and again at 3 PM. I can set the start time and an interval of 7 hours, but that would mean the job would execute more than twice a day.

I could change the schedule on the Azure portal, but I don't want to do that every time I deploy. Is it possible to set an array of start times in the publish setting JSON file?
The schema file can be found here: http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the cron-expression like that:

```
0 0 8,15 * * *
```

This will execute your job at 8AM and 3PM every day.

[From the documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON) :

```
*    *    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or    use names)
│    │    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    |    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
└────────────────────────────── second(0 - 59)
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually used a Scheduler job: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2015/05/scheduled-webjob.html

Since I want to publish from Visual studio without worrying about the schedule, this works best I think.

Comment: Could the person who gave this answer a -1 please explain why?